# Why is default aptitude so out of date?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, aptitude

I'm trying to apt-get install python3.6, and all the solutions point to adding deadsnakes or other ppas/ building from source. My question is why are the default apt repos so out of date? Seems odd that something like python would be so much trouble to get running, especially since it's now on 3.8...

Comment: Did you try to update your repos? `apt-get update`?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Need to eat crow on this one. It turns out that you can't

*apt-get install python=3.6*

But you can

*apt-get install python3.6*

and then

*ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python*

But

*apt-get install python=3.5*

still works, so it's confusing.